# Grammar rectification

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> If a monotone class, $\mathcal M$ is closed under finite intersections, is it a $\sigma$-algebra ?

We can show that a monotone class is closed under complement using first two properties:

Say $E$ is the whole set, then $E\in\mathcal M$ (1.property)

If $A,B\in\mathcal M$ and $A\subset B$ then $B\setminus A\in\mathcal M$ (we take $E$ instead of $B$, then $A^c$ belongs to $\mathcal M$)

Since we have assumed that finite intersections are allowed

$A_n\in\mathcal M\Rightarrow\bigcap_1^nA_n\in\mathcal M\Rightarrow\bigcup_1^nA_n^c\in\mathcal M$

but always for finite union of sets (we need countably many).

Comment: What is your definition of monotone class? If it's stable by countable non-dereasing unions, you will be done.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo If non-decreasing is increasing, yes. That's the 3rd property, $A_n\in\mathcal M$, $A_n\subset A_{n+1}$ $\Rightarrow\bigcup_n A_n\in\mathcal M$

Comment: $S_N:=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{N}$ then $S_N$ are increasing therefore $\bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb N}S_n\in\mathcal M$, is that correct ?